# Using Ruby coreaudio gem

Tags: objective-c, ruby, rubygems

I'm creating an audio project as an academic exercise - I want to use Ruby for a non-rails project. I came across the coreaudio gem here: https://github.com/nagachika/ruby-coreaudio and thought it would be useful in playing back the audio I'm creating. However, there are some basic things I'm just not getting about this gem.

1) Is there any documentation? I would be happy to volunteer to contribute to the project by writing documentation but I'm afraid I lack the basic understanding to do so. I looked at the generated documentation here: http://rubydoc.info/gems/coreaudio/ but that's only more mysterious. I would think that would at least show the method prototypes but I only see one method `CoreAudio::AudioFile:read`. The examples have calls to other methods that don't show up here.

2) What are the available methods / is there an API? The examples have things like `CoreAudio.default_input_device.input_buffer` and `CoreAudio.default_output_device.output_stream`, and by copying the examples I have been able to get some sound out through the `CoreAudio.default_output_device.output_buffer`. `default_input_device` and `default_output_device` are instances of `CoreAudio::AudioDevice`. This is awesome, but I don't know what `CoreAudio::AudioDevice` is.

3) What is CoreAudio::AudioDevice? Having no more sophisticated tools at my disposal I grepped for the string 'AudioDevice' in the installed gem files. I found a number of instances in the file /ext/coreaudio.m. The code looks like C and I think .m is a file suffix for a certain type of file in an Objective C project. The only place in that file where I see the string 'AudioDevice' where it isn't part of a larger variable name (eg: rb_cAudioDevice) is in the comments, but I'm guessing that this objective C code gets compiled into... I don't know what...

4) What are these Objective C files doing here? Where's the Ruby? Shouldn't there be a file or files written in Ruby somewhere in this project that define the class CoreAudio::AudioDevice? The only .rb file on any appreciable size is lib/coreaudio/audiofile.rb (where the read method is defined, the only method shown in rdoc).

5) What is coreaudio_ext.bundle? The gem installation process created a binary file called coreaudio_ext.bundle which, if I had to guess, would be the result of compiling the objective C files in the project. This file is required in lib/coreaudio/coreaudio.rb, so must be significant to Ruby, but it's a black box to me. I assume it is a black box containing the definition of the ephemeral CoreAudio::AudioDevice. How would I know how to use this other than looking at the examples?

Please help me understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Your guess in 5 is correct. Also, for 4, it is possible to define classes, methods etc that are available to Ruby, but fully implemented and declared in C. In fact if you know a little C, it's quite easy to integrate C and MRI Ruby. I cannot say how to use the gem unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Neil - I had never seen this done before, though I'm sure I will if I'm working with audio. I'll do some research into the process of integrating C with MRI Ruby and see if I find more answers there. I do know a 'little' C though probably not enough to make it easy :)

Comment: I wrote an *example* here (which I use as a template when building new gems): https://github.com/neilslater/ruby_nex_c - The best starter reference (IMO) is http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Since I asked, I'll attempt to document my answer for any future archaeologists who may puzzle with the same questions. Thanks to Neil Slater, for pointing me in the direction of important resources needed to answer my question(s).

1) Is there any documentation? - not really. The `CoreAudio::AudioFile:read` function is the only one documented by rdoc because everything else is implemented in a Ruby extension in C, by the mechanism described in detail here: http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf. Turns out that this process has been done for a great number of existing C libraries to add their functionality to Ruby.

2) What are the available methods / is there an API? - The extension created is the equivalent of the following: (corrections welcome)

```
Module CoreAudio

  class AudioDevice
    attr_reader :devid, :name, :available_sample_rate, :nominal_rate, :input_stream, :output_stream

    def initialize(devIdVal, options)
      ...
    end

    def actual_rate
      ...
    end

    def output_loop(frame)
      ...
    end

    def output_buffer(frame)
      ...
    end

    def input_buffer(frame)
      ...
    end
  end

  class AudioStream
    attr_reader :channels, :buffer_frame_size

    def initialize(devid_val, is_input)
      ...
    end
  end

  class OutLoop
    def []=(index, val)
      ...
    end

    def start
      ...
    end

    def stop
      ...
    end
  end

  class AudioBuffer
    def start
      ...
    end

    def stop
      ...
    end

    def dropped_frame
      ...
    end

    def reset_dropped_frame
      ...
    end

    def space
      ...
    end

  end

  class OutputBuffer
    def <<(nary)
      ...
    end
  end

  class InputBuffer
    def read(num)
      ...
    end
  end

  def devices
    ...
  end

  def default_input_device
    ...
  end

  def default_output_device
    ...
  end

  def set_default_output_device
    ...
  end

  class AudioFile
    def initialize
      ...
    end

    def close
      ...
    end

    def write(data)
      ...
    end

    def read_frames(frame_val)
      ...
    end

    def rate
      ...
    end

    def channels
      ...
    end

    def inner_rate
      ...
    end

    def inner_channels
      ...
    end

  end
end
```

3) What is CoreAudio::AudioDevice? - I was mistaken about the string "AudioDevice" not appearing on its own as an identifier - it appears in the C code as follows:

```
rb_cAudioDevice = rb_define_class_under(rb_mCoreAudio, "AudioDevice", rb_cObject);
```

this is declaring the class AudioDevice inside of module CoreAudio.

4) Where's the Ruby? - this gem is extending Ruby with coreaudio, written in C.

5) What is coreaudio_ext.bundle? this is the compiled C code. It's required by the gem in coreaudio.rb

```
require "coreaudio/coreaudio_ext"
```

A .bundle file is the Mac equivalent of a .dll file in Windows. (I don't believe there is a Windows implementation of this gem, as CoreAudio is a Mac-specific technology)